# Return '0' INT while reading XML attribute in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

How can I return INT value `0` instead of `NULL` from XML? Please consider the following:

```
DECLARE @xml XML ='<asset> <cnfg categ="Desktop" type="hj" device="3"/></asset>';        

DECLARE @Str1 INT;
DECLARE @Str2 INT;

SELECT  @Str1 = ParamValues.Content.value('@dev', 'int'),
        @Str2 = ParamValues.Content.value('@device', 'int') 
FROM @xml.nodes('/asset/cnfg') as ParamValues(Content)

SELECT @Str1, @str2
```

The above code returns `NULL,3`, but I want to get the result as `0,3`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You should be explicit about the database you are using, which I suspect is SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT @Str1 = COALESCE(ParamValues.Content.value('@dev', 'int'), 0),
       @Str2 = COALESCE(ParamValues.Content.value('@device', 'int'), 0)
FROM @xml.nodes('/asset/cnfg') as ParamValues(Content)
```

Answer (score 1):

The same can be achieved like below too -

The query -

```
DECLARE @xml XML 
SET @xml='<asset><cnfg categ="Desktop" type="hj" device="3"/></asset>'
DECLARE @Str1 INT,@Str2 INT
SELECT @Str1 = ISNULL(ParamValues.Content.value('(@dev)[1]', 'int'),0),
       @Str2 = ISNULL(ParamValues.Content.value('(@device)[1]', 'int'),0) 
FROM @xml.nodes('/asset/cnfg') as ParamValues(Content)
SELECT @Str1, @str2
```

**Edit:** Changed the query due to wrong XML type considered.